# multiply coda sliders on same page

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, coda-slider

I have been using the jQuery Coda-Slider v2.0 by Kevin Batdorf (http://www.ndoherty.biz/coda-slider) for my current project.

Now I want to add another slider to the same page but with a different width.

Ive tried to prepending ids to the .panel and .coda-slider classes but seems that the codaslider fails to fetch the width after adding id. Anyone succeeded in adding multiply coda sliders with different width to the same page?

This is what Ive tried:

**Original**

```
.coda-slider, .coda-slider .panel {
    width: 300px;
}
```

**Altered**

```
#myslider1 .coda-slider, #myslider1 .coda-slider .panel {
    width: 300px;
}

#myslider2 .coda-slider, #myslider2 .coda-slider .panel {
    width: 600px;
}
```

---

**EDIT**
Check out this [example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/ttcHq/1/). You will see two working sliders on same page, how to make them different width?

---

Answer (score 1):

I edited your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttcHq/2/) and added this:

```
#slider1 {
    width: 300px;
}

#slider2 {
    width: 600px;
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks, yes I know - both panel and coda-slider are descendants of #myslider1 and #myslider2

Comment: Ok, then I guess we need to see the markup and script you are using to create sliders. Could make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?